# Elastic Transcoder AWS, How do I increase thumbnail size?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, coffeescript

Is there a key or something i can use to set the height and width of thumbnail from the video im transcoding?

```
transcodeVideo = (fileName, cb) ->
        elastictranscoder = new (AWS.ElasticTranscoder)(apiVersion: '2012-09-25')
        elastictranscoder.createJob {
          PipelineId: process.env.PIPELINE_ID
          OutputKeyPrefix: fileName + '/'
          Input:
            Key: fileName
            FrameRate: 'auto'
            Resolution: 'auto'
            AspectRatio: 'auto'
            Interlaced: 'auto'
            Container: 'auto'
          Output:
            Key: 'video.mp4'
            Resolution: 'auto'
            ThumbnailPattern: 'thumbs-{count}'
            PresetId: process.env.PRESET_ID
            Rotate: 'auto'
        }, cb
```

Answer (score 5):

This is a property of the Transcoding Preset.

When creating a new transcoding preset, you can specify the format/height/width/interval of the thumbnails.

Unfortunately it doesn't look like this is something that can be changed dynamically on a per-job basis.

[image: Thumbnail section of the AWS Elastic Transcoding console when creating a Transcoding Preset]